# How to change the default AnchorPoint to 0.5, 0.5 in Swift

Tags: swift, xcode

I don't know if its just me but I just noticed that the default AnchorPoint was changed to 0, 0. How can i change it back to 0.5, 0.5? or if its not possible to change the default AnchorPoint then please show me how i can change it for a SKSpriteNote because this doesn't work anymore:

```
sprite.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
```

Comment: Are you sure you didn't change it? Docs still say it's 0.5 https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/skspritenode/1519877-anchorpoint

Comment: maybe i accidentally did sometime but i don't know how to change it back to 0.5, 0.5, could you tell me?

Comment: tbh, until you posted this, I didn't even know the default could be changed! ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0):

you can change it from sks file easily from options.

[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0dj2g.png)